# Classical statistical model based on group multiplication

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, topological-phase, spin-models

For a (finite) group $G$, consider the following classical statistical model on a 2 dimensional lattice with oriented edges:

Each edge carries a classical degree of freedom that can take values in the group $G$. At each vertex there is a Boltzmann weight of:

\begin{equation}
\omega(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if} \quad a_1^{\epsilon_1}a_2^{\epsilon_2}\ldots=1\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are the group elements at the edges around the vertex, in cyclic order, and $\epsilon=\pm 1$ depending on whether the edge is oriented towards the vertex or not.

Has this model been studied? In which phase is it? (I would already be happy for an answer in a simple special case, say $G=Z_3$).

Comment: How is this different from lattice gauge theory for the group $G$ (and shouldn't it be dual to the corresponding Potts model)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I'm not sure what people mean when they say "lattice gauge theory for group $G$" but I assume it's the same or related to the quantum double model for $G$? This is a quantum 2+1 dimensional model whereas the model above is a classical 2 dimensional model. The corresponding 1+1 dimensional quantum model is directly equivalent to the (quantum version of the) [Nr. irreps of $G$]-state Potts model by a Fourier transform. Slowly performing the Fourier transform gives a path between the two models without a phase transition... (continued)

Comment: However, in the classical case this path is not possible as the Fourier transform (unless for $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^n$) has non-real entries, so we would need non-real Boltzmann weights along the way. Is there still another obvious path involving only real Boltzmann weights?